# when to use properties file and when to look out for database?

Tags: java, database, properties

All:

I have a scenario to maintain the configuration data. As far as my understanding goes, we can store the configuration data either in a Properties file or in a flat table.

I am in the lookout of a valid demarcation that provides when to make use of properties and when to use database tables.

As far as my understanding goes, storing config data in properties is cheaper w.r.to the cost and efficiency of the API (in case of Java based app) than database (as establishing connection for the sake of this purpose is costly)

Your comments are welcomed!

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I would assume you'd only load the configuration data once or rarely anyway, so I wouldn't worry too much about the performance side of things. A few points to consider though:

- If you don't *just* need name/value pairs, a database is likely to provide a richer data model.
- Storing the configuration in a database is likely to make it easier to share between multiple computers
- Even with configuration in the database you'll need to configure the database connection itself...
- Using a database for configuration *if you don't need a database for anything else* would seem a little odd, although you could potentially consider using an *embedded* database such as SQLite instead of a traditional client/server one.
- Don't forget there are other alternatives beyond the two you've mentioned

Answer (score 2):

A properties file contains static values, fixed at compile time (or deployment time). A database contains dynamic values, that you can change while the application is running.

Comment: my requirement is more on the configuration information that doesn't change overtime. you can take it as constants for the entire suite of applications.

Comment: then properties files are easier, faster, and less dangerous. And they can be stored in your VCS, too.

Answer (score 1):

While the service is not aggregating tonnes of configs, efficiency is not a key here. 
There're a few questions which may help:

- Is config data is complex? Yes? - DB storage
- Will data be reloaded rarely? Yes? - property file
- Is service has many instances? Yes? Do I want to support the config management system like Puppet? Yes? - property file
- Is service has many instances? Yes? Will service need A/B testing? Yes? - property file
- Will I need to update config urgently without restart? Yes? - DB storage (excluding case with Archaius)
- Do I need to track config update? Yes? - DB storage
- Does service have many logically divided configs (e.g services connections configs in microservices)? Yes? - property file
- Is config data sensitive? (e.g secret tokens, creds) - property file

Answer (score -1):

There is comparision between **Properties file** and **database**. **Properties file** stores **key value** pairs separated by **= or :** and both **key and value** must be **string**.

You can store any data in a 2d tabular format in database.